# Copy in folder and package with publish

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

Is there a way to copy the files includes in `package.json` (in the `File` field) to a folder to package them together with `npm publish`?

**My repo:**

```
.
├── package.json
└── folder0
    ├── file0
    └── folder1
       └── file1
```

**My package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "files": [
    "folder0/file0",
    "folder0/folder1/file1"
  ],
  "author": "cruiz"
}
```

---

**Desired output:**

I want in my package:

```
.
├── package.json
└── build
    ├── file0
    └── file1
```

---

#### EDIT:

Thank you very much for the reply. I'm trying to use npm to package VHDL code, so I'm really noob :(

Is it possible to put the files to be packaged in a field of package.json and read them from the script?

```json
{ 
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "customField": [
    "folder0/file0",
    "folder0/folder1/file1"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "mkdirp build && copyfiles -f [..read CustomField...] build"
  },
  "author": "cruiz"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Revised Answer:

Edit based on the OP's edit.

> *Is it possible to put the files to be packaged in a field of `package.json` and read them from the script.*

Yes that's possible, however you will need to utilize a custom node script to do that. There's no existing packages available to achieve this that I am aware of.

**Solution:**

1. Firstly, `cd` to your project directory and uninstall the packages I mentioned in by original answer as we wont be using them. You can do this by running the following command:

   ```
   npm un -D mkdirp copyfile
   ```
2. Install [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) using the following command:

   ```
   npm i -D shelljs
   ```

   **Note**: `shelljs` will now be utlized instead of `mkdirp` and `copyfile` to create the directory then copy the files listed in `package.json`.
3. Next create a node script with the following contents. Lets name the file `copy-files.js` and save it to a hidden directory named `.scripts` at the top level of your project directory. I.e.

   **Directory structure**

   ```
   project
   ├── .scripts
   │   └── copy-files.js
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   ├── folder0
   │   ├── file0.js
   │   └── folder1
   │      └── file1.js
   └── ...
   ```

   **Contents of `copy-files.js`**

   ```js
   const shell = require('shelljs');
   const pkg = require('../package.json');

   // The path to the directory to copy the file(s) to.
   const DEST_DIR = './build';

   // NOTE: `customField` below should be replaced with the
   // actual key name in the final `package.json`.
   const srcFilePaths = pkg.customField;

   // Create a new destination directory and intermediate
   // directories if necessary.
   if (!shell.test('-d', DEST_DIR)) {
     shell.mkdir('-p', DEST_DIR);
   }

   // Recursively copy each file listed in the `customField` Array.
   // Logs and error if the file listed cannot be found.
   srcFilePaths.forEach(function (srcPath) {
     if (!shell.test('-e', srcPath)) {
       shell.echo('Error: Cannot find file listed in package.json: %s', srcPath);
       process.exit(1);
     }
     shell.cp(srcPath, DEST_DIR);
   });
   ```

   **Note**: The `customField` part in `const srcFilePaths = pkg.customField;`, (on line 9 of `copy-files.js` above), will need to  be replaced with the actual real key name you decide to use in the final `package.json`.
4. Finally, update your `prepublishOnly` script to invoke the custom node script (i.e. `copy-file.js`) as shown in the following excerpt of `package.json`:

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "customField": [
       "folder0/file0.js",
       "folder0/folder1/file1.js"
     ],
     "scripts": {
       "prepublishOnly": "node .scripts/copy-files",
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

---

### Original Answer

This can be achieved by utilizing a custom [npm-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in your `package.json` file. Using a `pre` script will also suit your requriement as you mentioned:

> *package them together with `npm publish`*

---

#### 1. Using `pre` and `post` hooks with npm scripts:

All npm scripts support what are referred to as `pre` and `post` hooks. Any `pre` script will run before its respective script (or command), and any `post` script will run after its respective script (or command).

To better understand this feature let's say our `package.json` contains the contrived scripts shown in the following excerpt:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "prefoo": "...",
  "foo": "...",
  "postfoo": "..."
},
...
```

As you can see:

1. There is a script named `foo` which has a corresponding script with the `pre` prefix, i.e. `prefoo`.
2. Similarly, the same `foo` script also has another corresponding script, however this one is prefixed with `post`, i.e. `postfoo`.

Specifying scripts in this way will result in the following whenever you invoke the `foo` script via your CLI by running `npm run foo`:

1. The `prefoo` script will automatically run before the `foo` script is executed.
2. The `postfoo` will automatically run after `foo` completes.

Further information regarding `pre` and `post` hooks can be found [here](http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html#hooks-pre-and-post)

---

#### 2. So which `pre` script should I use?

There are a couple of built-in `pre` scripts that are likely to suit your requirement; those being `prepublish` or `prepublishOnly`. The npm docs provides the following description for these hooks:

- > **prepublish**: Run BEFORE the package is packed and published, as well as on local `npm install` without any arguments. (See below)
- > **prepublishOnly**: Run BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on `npm publish`...

*Note: The following solution uses the `prepublishOnly` as I'm quite sure you don't want this script to run when a user runs `npm install`. However, you'll need to decide whether to use this or swap it for `prepublish`. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for the finer details of each `pre` hook.*

---

#### 3. Solution

1. For a solution that works *cross platforms* you'll need to firstly `cd` to your project directory and install a couple of additional npm packages.

   - Install [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) by running: `npm i -D mkdirp`
   - Install [copyfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) by running: `npm i -D copyfiles`
2. In the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file add the following:

   ```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "prepublishOnly": "mkdirp build && copyfiles -f folder0/file0.js folder0/folder1/file1.js build"
   },
   ...
   ```

Now when you run; `npm run publish`, the `prepublishOnly` script will automatically run, (i.e. copy the files to meet your desired directory structure), before your package is prepared and packed for publishing.

You can of course run; `npm run prepublishOnly`, if you'd like to test the results of the script before running: `npm run publish`.

Comment: Im having a problem. When I use the package with git dependencies npm doesnt run the script.

Comment: "dependencies": {                                                                                      
    "IPCoreSlave": "git+http://arx.da.pex.com/gitlab/cruiz/IPCoreSlave.git#v4.0.0"                                                                                 
  },

Comment: It's unclear to me what your new issue is? Remember a `prepublishOnly` script runs only BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, (i.e. ONLY on `npm publish`)

Comment: OK! :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936732/npm-script-with-git-depenency

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is a build step. You could do all those things in a `prepublish` script, e.g.:

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "mkdir -p build && cp folder0/file0 folder0/folder1/file1 build"
  }
}
```

But you should change your `files` as well, unless you really want *both* structures, in `build` and `folder0/*`.

Comment: I have added new info about my problem.

Comment: I have extended my question.